# Device memory flush cuda

Tags: cuda, gpu

I'm running a C program where I call twice a cuda host function. I want to clean up the device memory between these 2 calls. Is there a way I can flush GPU device memory?? I'm on a Tesla M2050 with computing capability of 2.0

Comment: Could you be a little more precise with what you mean by "flush" or "clean up"? Do you mean you want to zero the memory, or set it to some other known non-initialised value, or do you mean something else? And do you want to "flush" just memory you have allocated, or do you mean the whole device?

Comment: I'd like to zero the memory i've allocated, to "forget" the values that were stored there by the various kernels.Sorry for the vagueness of the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you only want to zero the memory, then `cudaMemset` is probably the simplest way to do this. For example:

```
const int n = 10000000;
const int sz = sizeof(float) * n;
float *devicemem;
cudaMalloc((void **)&devicemem, sz);

kernel<<<...>>>(devicemem,....);
cudaMemset(devicemem, 0, sz); // zeros all the bytes in devicemem
kernel<<<...>>>(devicemem,....);
```

Note that the value `cudaMemset` takes is a *byte* value, and all bytes in the specified range are set to that value, just like the standard C `memset`. If you have a specific *word* value, then you will need to write your own memset kernel to assign the values.

Comment: To memset 16- and 32-bit values, you can call the driver API's cuMemset* family of functions, e.g. cuMemsetD16() or cuMemsetD32(), even from CUDA runtime applications.

Comment: @talonmies: thanks for all your help with CUDA answers on SO.  Can you contact me directly (First Initial Last Name At My Company Dot Com)? I have a  question for you (sorry, SO doesn't support private messages).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Thrust vectors, then you can call `thrust::fill()` on the vector you want to reset with the reset value you want.

```
thrust::device_vector< FooType > fooVec( FooSize );
kernelCall1<<< x, y >>>( /* Pass fooVec here */ );

// Reset memory of fooVec
thrust::fill( fooVec.begin(), fooVec.end(), FooDefaultValue );

kernelCall2<<< x, y >>>( /* Pass fooVec here */ );
```